# how to insert an array at user specified position in another array & get the resultant array?

Tags: c, arrays, insert

The problem occurs when shifting the resulting array to right after insertion of second array at specified position.Please note no rotation, circular or reverse required.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i, n, m, location, b[20], a[20];
    printf("Enter the number of elements in first array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter the elements of first array : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the location to insert second array : \n");
    scanf("%d", &location);
    printf("Enter the number of elements in second array :\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the elements of second array : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    for (i = m; i >= location; i--) {
        a[i + n] = a[i];
    }
    a[location + i] = b[i];
    m++;  

    printf("Resulting array after insertion is : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

After running the program. I get this which is incorrect.

```
Enter the number of elements in first array:
3

Enter the elements of first array : 
10 20 30

Enter the location to insert second array : 
1

Enter the number of elements in second array :
2

Enter the elements of second array : 
55 66

Resulting array after insertion is : 
10 55 30 20
```

Comment: Is the output you show the *actual* output, or the *expected* output? Can you please show both? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I also suggest that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just adding the one element of `b` to `a`

Replace your

```
 a[location+i] = b[i];
  m++;
```

With

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     a[location+i] = b[i];
  }

  m+=n;
```

Because you need to loop through the `b` array to add all the elements into `a` array.

Comment: What happens when I enter elements greater than the size of the array like below:                                                                                                    Enter the number of elements in first array:
2
Enter the elements of first array : 
1 2 3
Enter the location to insert second array : 
Enter the number of elements in second array :
0
Enter the elements of second array : 
Resulting array after insertion is : 
1 2

Answer (score 0):

You had better create a new array c[40]

```
for(i=0;i<n+m;i++){
    //keep first part of b
    if (i<location){
        c[i]=b[i]
    }
    //insert a
    if (i>=location&&i<location+m){
        c[i]=a[i-location]
    }
    //rest part of b
    if (i>=location+m){
        c[i]=b[i-m]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. After moving the elements of array `a` from `location` to the extent
   of the length of array `b` (which you are doing correctly), **you
   also have to copy every element of array `b` into array `a` from
   `location` onwards** (which you are not doing).
2. After that you have to print array `a` whose size is now incremented by
       the size of array `b`